# Cannot get GDB's simulator for Cortex-M3 (ARM) to work

Tags: gdb, arm, simulator

I need to use the simulator and for a start I wanted to do something real simple: Step thru the first few instructions of my startup code. Here it is:
    Reset_Handler:
      movs r1, #0
      b LoopCopyDataInit
    CopyDataInit:
      ldr r3, =_sidata
      ldr r3, [r3, r1]
      str r3, [r0, r1]
      adds r1, r1, #4
    LoopCopyDataInit:

And this is what happens with GDB:
e:\devtools\Olimex\examples\STM32-P103_UART1>e:/devtools/olimex/yagarto/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe main.out
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i686-pc-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/...
Reading symbols from e:\devtools\Olimex\examples\STM32-P103_UART1/main.out...done.
(gdb) target sim
Connected to the simulator.
(gdb) load
Loading section .isr_vector, size 0x10c vma 0x8000000
Loading section .text, size 0x1788 vma 0x800010c
Loading section .data, size 0x28 vma 0x20000000
Start address 0x800183d
Transfer rate: 50656 bits in <1 sec.
(gdb) b Reset_Handler
Breakpoint 1 at 0x800183e: file ./lib/startup_stm32f10x_md.s, line 67.
(gdb) b CopyDataInit
Breakpoint 2 at 0x8001840: file ./lib/startup_stm32f10x_md.s, line 71.
(gdb) run
Starting program: e:\devtools\Olimex\examples\STM32-P103_UART1/main.out
sim: unknown SWI encountered - 93 - ignoring
Unhandled v6 thumb insn: b64d
sim: exception: Unhandled Instruction '0x00000004' at 0xea021aca.  Stopping.

[Thread ] #1 stopped.
0x00000b90 in ?? ()
(gdb)

The start address looks ok, I set 2 breakpoints after the first few instructions but they are never reached. What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
M'

Comment: the vector table for a cortex-m is at address 0x0000.  is your simulator specific to the stm32 where I assume the address space is remapped (by the factory bootloader)?  What happens when you build for 0x00000000 instead of 0x8000...?

Comment: actually I think it is the straps not the bootloader that maps the user flash to zero.  different strap settings map the bootloader to zero...

Comment: it looks like you have a massive program for something that has not booted yet.  start simpler.

Comment: Well, the memory (as per STM's linker scripts) starts at 0x08000000 - and the example programs all work on the real board (with the same linker script). But I will try out your suggestion and build for 0x00000000. Thanks for replying.

Comment: right, the straps map in different spaces to 0x00000000 to boot, but that is the silicon, I cant imagine the gdb cortex-m simulator simulating all the hardware nuances of all the different chips out there.

Comment: No, it certainly couldn't know about all the hardware out there. But it _should_ simulate the Cortex-M instructions, shouldn't it. BTW, building for 0x00000000 didn't change anything.

Comment: gdb's internal simulator is the classic armulator from arm, so it doesnt support cortex-m3.  it does support thumb (not thumb2 extensions) but it boots like an arm not like a cortex-m.  qemu has a cortex-m3 simulator but I dont know the status.  the first cortex-m3 chips, stellaris from luminary micro (was bought by ti and is now the tiva c series) had/have a qemu simulator machine